# Send mail from my web page with ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-app-engine, email

I am trying to build an error reporting service for my web page. The idea is simple. If an error pops up in a client browser while visiting, I want an error handler to send me notofication about it. My page is static, so I want to avoid adding server side components for that. Can I use ajax request for example and use a gmail account to send the mail to me? I guess ajax does not do cross domain? Maybe there is some other option?

EDIT

My primary language is Java.
What about Google App engine? I can host an app there that can send email. Not sure how I can interact with that app though?

Other idea - if I must use server side component, maybe the best option is to find ready web application (I have java application server running on my host) that sends mail and deploy it. Then I can contact the mail sender with Ajax.

Comment: I am not sure that you can send email without having any server side component.

Comment: You can build your mailing application that receives an error string and host it on Google App Engine. You will have to do some JS scripting on your own page so it can communicate with your app via the GoogleAppEngine API whenever there is an error.

Comment: Yes, you can send Email with App Engine. http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/appengine/docs/java/mail/usingjavamail.html

Comment: Thanks guys but the problem remains. How does my script contact my google app engine application when it is hosted on other domain?

Comment: Using the App Engine SDK ! Check out this section of the app engine documentation. http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/

Comment: Gael, You just linked to the start of the documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to do this is the following:

1. You need to set up a web service that accepts the error information.
2. The web service will generate the email content and send to gmail.
3. The client (via ajax) will consume this web service and post the error information.

This way your credentials are secure on your server. If you indicate the development language, we may be able to help with a bit more details.

Bob

Comment: Thanks, please see my EDIT. Is there reliable, open source, Java, web component suitable for this task? If it accepts Ajax and is packaged as WAR, it would be perfect!

Answer (score 1):

If you were to be using GMail then you would:

- Be using a server side component (GMail's scripts!)
- Have to expose your GMail credentials to every visitor (bad!)
- Do cross domain Ajax with a third party service (which requires a pretty recent browser and the cooperation of the third party).

You need your own server side handler for this.

Comment: The problem is, that any third party will also need to be contacted with Ajax and will be sitting on other domain. I can do cross domain get request with ease using little tricks, like trying to load an image source that has all the paramaters included. But it is ugly sollution

Answer (score 0):

You can, ... theoretically. You do not want to, because you would have to send the authentication information for your e-mail account to the client.